# Unity Networking Turn Based Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I want help in unity networking, I am developing a online multiplayer ludo game. I have completed offline version. But I am stuck in networking . My question is where should I put network manager in menu scene or in game scene? and please explain how    to use network manager to make my game.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see the [ask] section on how to ask a good question. This will help you get good answers or direct you to another question with a solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is too broad for [what we serve here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) so I'd suggest starting with the extensive [Unity Documentation of Multiplayer Networking](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetOverview.html), trying things out, and returning with a more focused question when you run into issues. When you do you might also want to checkout the [Game Dev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) where you will find more game-specific contributors.

Comment: AS per my Knowledge,you should create a Custom Network Manager and Load that online Scene from that.here is a link that i find helpful-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w2kwGDZ6wM